# How to display the group of a choice in a Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a hierarchical choices structure in my data model, like this one (but a lot longer):

```
MEDIA_CHOICES = (
('Audio', (
        ('vinyl', 'Vinyl'),
        ('cd', 'CD'),
    )
),
('Video', (
        ('vhs', 'VHS Tape'),
        ('dvd', 'DVD'),
    )
),
)
```

and I have a template to display the object these choices connect to.

While I can retrieve the names of the bottom-level choices (e.g. "VHS Tape") to display in my template, I can't figure how to retrieve the category headings (e.g. "Video").

I'm sure it must be possible though, as Django does it when rendering a form to create these objects.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897731/grouped-checkboxselectmultiple-in-django-template . This might help you.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to figure the relationship - I'm trying to create a view on the data, not to create a form that interacts with it. I've managed to work around my need to solve this problem for the near-term by creating a new model and connecting to that one with the choice and its parent as separate properties there. However, I still would like to figure if there is a way to get the "Audio" or "Video" out, given the media = "vhs" as an element of the model.