# Django ModelMultipleChoiceField: passing attributes unique to each choice

Tags: python, django, forms, modelform

I have a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` on a form that I'd like to pass an attribute to each item in the QuerySet.  I need this attribute to be determined dynamically. So for example if `Item` objects with the names `` `item1' `` and `'item2'`:

```
Item.object.create(name='item1')
Item.object.create(name='item2')

items = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Item.objects,
                                       widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
                                       required=True)
```

---

```
<input class="item1" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input class="item2" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

Is there a way to do this in the form class?  Or should I just suck it up and manually write out the form?

Comment: could you clarify, do you need just a custom queryset for your form field that needs to be determined dynamically?

Comment: suck it up.. otherwise you would have to customize renderer, which is to much overhead in my opinion (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13934149/1566605)

Comment: Hey andrean, that is exactly what I need.  I have just manually written out the form, but still curious if there is a better way.

Comment: After some research I think the proper way to do what I want is to override the CheckboxSelectMultiple widget.  Will post solution if it works out.