# Django: drop-down list

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu, organization

I have a model 'Post,' which is just a like a blog post:

```
class Post(models.Model):
```

Each post has a pub_date attribute:

```
pub_date = models.DateField()
```

When displaying posts on my site, I'd like to have an simple, drop-down menu at the top of the page with a structure like:

- 2014

  - Jan
  - Feb
- 2013
- 2012

and so on. I can't figure out how to sort my posts like this with Django, and I think it would be bad practice to hard code it. How would you solve this?

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897731/grouped-checkboxselectmultiple-in-django-template. It is not exactly same but you can have an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
posts = Post.objects.all()
sortedposts = {}
for p in posts:
    sortedposts.setdefault(p.pub_date.year, {})\
               .setdefault(p.pub_date.strftime('%b'), [])\
               .append(p)
```

Which would give you the structure:

```
sortedposts = {
    2014: {
      'Jan': [<post4>, <post3>], 
      'Feb': [<post2>]
    },
    2013: {
      'Jul': [<post1>]
    }
}
```