# Django 1.8 Group CheckboxSelectMultiple from Model / Queryset

Tags: django, checkbox, django-1.8

I want to do this:

```
MEDIA_CHOICES = (
    ('Audio', (
        ('vinyl', 'Vinyl'),
        ('cd', 'CD'),
        )
    ),
    ('Video', (
        ('vhs', 'VHS Tape'),
        ('dvd', 'DVD'),
        )
    ),
    ('unknown', 'Unknown'),
    )
```

but from a queryset.  Here's my Model:

```
class ScoreMsg(models.Model):
    scoremsg = models.TextField(db_column='ScoreMsg',)
    category = models.CharField(db_column='Category', max_length=50,)
```

I want the CheckboxSelectMultiple in the same layout.  I found a solution at [Grouped CheckboxSelectMultiple in Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897731/grouped-checkboxselectmultiple-in-django-template) but that was 3 years ago and am hoping there's another way.  Cheers.

Here are my Models:

```
class ScoreMsg(models.Model):
    scoremsg = models.TextField(db_column='ScoreMsg', blank=True, null=True)
    evalgrp = models.ForeignKey(EvalGrp)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.scoremsg)

class EvaluationScore(models.Model):
    evaluation = models.OneToOneField(Evaluation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Evaluation",)
    scoremsg = SeparatedValuesField(db_column='ScoreMessage', max_length=300, token='|', blank=True, null=True)
```

and here are my forms:

```
class ScoreMsgChoiceField(ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ScoreMsgChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        groups = groupby(kwargs['queryset'], attrgetter('evalgrp'))
        self.choices = [(evalgrp, [(c.id, self.label_from_instance(c)) for c in scoremsgs])
                    for evalgrp, scoremsgs in groups]


class EvaluationScorefrm(forms.ModelForm):
    scoremsg = ScoreMsgChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'size':'300'}), queryset=ScoreMsg.objects.all(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = EvaluationScore
```

The HTML that is generated looks correct:

```
<div class="grp-td scoremsg ">

    <ul id="id_evaluationscore-0-scoremsg">
         <li>Vocabulary in General<ul id="id_evaluationscore-0-scoremsg_0"><li><label for="id_evaluationscore-0-scoremsg_0_0"><input id="id_evaluationscore-0-scoremsg_0_0" name="evaluationscore-0-scoremsg" size="300" type="checkbox" value="1" /> Excellent amount of vocabulary.</label></li>
         <li><label for="id_evaluationscore-0-scoremsg_0_1"><input id="id_evaluationscore-0-scoremsg_0_1" name="evaluationscore-0-scoremsg" size="300" type="checkbox" value="2" /> Good amount of vocabulary.  Always room for improvement.</label></li>
```

But when saved, the Label is stored in MySQL and not the Value:

```
id | evaluation_id | ScoreMessage                                                             
 1 |             1 | Good amount of vocabulary.  Always room for improvement.
```

Comment: In form constructor query db, create list of choices and assign to your field. Take a look at https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&q=django+forms+choicefield+dynamic+choices&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0CBkQvwUoAGoVChMIgrTD5931xwIVBdYsCh2LVw_r

Comment: Hey thanks, I did this and now O have a problem because the label is being saved and not the value.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: This shows the proper grouped Choices, but when I save, the Label is saved and not the Value.  Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to look at self.choices, that it has right structure. Then look at generated html. And then in the firebug (or chrome dev tools) look at what is sent to server.

Comment: I posted the html and it looks correct.  Sorry, Can you explain how to "look at what is sent to server"?

Comment: If you use Google Chrome browser, press F12 button - it will open dev tools. In the network tab check "Preserve log". And after you will submit form, a log record about your request will appears in the talbe. It will include information about data that browser sent to server

Comment: Hey, I'm in Dev tools, and looking at the log.  I can see the Header info, but not what was sent.  Which tab is it under?  I see Headers, Preview, Response, Cookies and Timing.  Preview and Reponse both say "Failed to load Respone data".  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: In the "Headers" tab, at bottom there is "Request Payload"

Comment: OK, found it.  the pertinent lines I guess are: 1
------WebKitFormBoundaryhcLfQ5ItGl0Rgm9H
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="evaluationscore-0-scoremsg"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryhcLfQ5ItGl0Rgm9H
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="evaluationscore-0-scoremsg"

6
------WebKitFormBoundaryhcLfQ5ItGl0Rgm9H
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="evaluationscore-0-evaluation"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryhcLfQ5ItGl0Rgm9H
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="evaluationscore-0-id"

1

Comment: I checked 3 boxes, 1,6 & 11.  I see 1 & 6, but no 11.  But then why is it showing the text in MySQL or is that due to the relationship? And why don't they show as checked when I open the form?

Comment: So I dont know what's wrong. If you can, create repository on github and post your code.

Comment: I think I know what's the problem...in my form.py I'm creating the checkbox via  scoremsg = ScoreMsgChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'size':'300'}), queryset=ScoreMsg.objects.all(), required=False)
so it's basically being set to a blank list.  It's actually saving correctly, but the relationship is showing the text in the table.  How do I set the boxes to checked from the database?  do I have to do something like:  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   super(EvaluationScorefrm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: ok, I put the model.py, admin.py and froms.py at https://github.com/mykljohn/eval.   thanks for the help

Comment: As I understand, in the database all saves correctly, but you want to show checkboxes in table, when you show list of EvaluationScore?

Comment: correct. i've saved the selections, but after saving, all the checkboxes are reset.  the when i bring up an old record

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong.  It IS saving the label  and not the Value

Comment: Sorry, but I dont know what is wrong