# Group query results in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to group some results from a query in a Django template. I've tried [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) with no success.

I have a tags model that has a parent tag like below and its related to my Board model which is also below:

```
class BoardTags(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(default='', null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    parent_tag = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Board(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False, blank=False, verbose_name=('Board_Title'))
    sub_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    board_description = models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=False)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(BoardTags, blank=True, related_name='board')
```

This is the view I'm using to create the board (it's where the board tags are supposed to show up):

```
class CreateBoard(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = models.Board
    template_name = 'board/board_form.html'
    select_related = ("user")
    form_class = BoardForm
```

I'm using this widget 'tags':forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple() to try get this result: 
[image: Screenshot of intended output]

The parent tag would be the 'Topics' and inside the nav tab I would like to have the checkboxes for the various tags that share that parent tag.

Any ideas on how to do this?

EDIT:
I think I'm misunderstanding regroup perhaps as I can't get it to work as a regular list. This is what I've tried:

```
{% regroup form.tags by form.parent_tag as tags_list %}

<ul>
{% for parent_tag in tags_list %}
    <li>{{ parent_tag.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for tag in parent_tag.list %}
            <li>{{ tag.name }}: {{ tag.description }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: `regroup` should work just fine. Please post the code you have tried. One thing to keep in mind about `regroup` is that it needs to receive data pre-sorted by the attribute you want to group by (here: the text value of the parent_tag), otherwise you would get repeated parent tags.

Comment: @EndreBoth thanks. Can you tell me where I'm going wrong with the example above?

Answer (score 0):

You still didn't show the view that sends the data to the template. Your for loops look fine, but you `regroup` should look something like this:

```
{% regroup form.tags by parent_tag as tags_list %}
```

For this to work, the individual objects in the `form.tags` collection need to have a `parent_tag` attribute or property.

As indicated in the comment, the objects in `form.tags` need to be already sorted by `parent_tag` for this to work, otherwise you'll get more than one group per `parent_tag`.

Comment: Cheers.  Perhaps some of my tags don't have parent_tags so I'm gonna go through them and try again

Comment: You don't need to have a `parent_tag` on all objects, sorry if I was unclear. If there are some without, then you'll get a group "None", but the grouping process still works. If it doesn't, the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Before trying `regroup`, maybe you should simply output the list ungrouped to confirm that the object structure is the way you think it is.

Comment: I think you're right, the problem might not be the regroup. I Think it's because I'm accessing the tags using "form.tags". This won't let me access any of the other parts of the model - e.g. when I try--  {% for tagging in form.tags %}
                                      #{{tagging.tag}} - {{tagging.choice_label}} - {{tagging.description}} -- the tag's description doesn't appear but the tag (as a checkbox) appears & so does the choice_label (as the name of the tag). Any clue what's going on here?

Comment: Turns out, there's actually no easy way to do this. This chap here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257050/overriding-djangos-checkboxselectmultiple-widget-for-awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/39260371#39260371) has a soln to override some defaults. I'm gonna give it a go. Thanks all the same @Endre both

Comment: Bad link above, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897731/grouped-checkboxselectmultiple-in-django-template