# Django form with grouped checkboxes

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

I need to create a form in Django which contains a list of **grouped checkboxes** like:

```
group_one
  [] option_one
  [] option_two
group_two
  [] option_one
  [] options_three
```

Right now I've an intermediate table where I'm storing a `option_id` and a `group_id`.

I found this [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897731/grouped-checkboxselectmultiple-in-django-template/13934149#13934149) but only works on Django 1.8, after that version some classes were removed from the core of django forms...

I could find the way to update the snippet, but I wonder if maybe somebody had the same situation and found a better solution for this challenge.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've just posted a solution to this problem over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52815347/393652

Comment: That's really nice @MattRowbum! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (not tested)

```
from django import forms
set_a = (("a", "A"),
         ("b", "B"),)

set_b = (("c", "C"),
         ("d", "D"),)

    class Test(forms.Form):
        group_a = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                         choices=set_a)
        group_a = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                         choices=set_b)
```

Comment: Thanks @ojas-kale!. It could be a good idea, but I've an intermediate model which I use to store different options(_id) all of them are grouped by a group_id. It means technically that I could create an unknown number of options by group and I could have an unknown number of groups with checkboxes.

Do you have another idea?