# Is it possible to have a dropdown list containing multiple choices for Django models fields?

Tags: django

I'm a newbie to Django and having questions relate to models. Hope that everyone can shed some lights on this. Much appreciated!

I'm defining a model, called Customer. It has a **membership** field with **choices** option. I want to register the model to Admin page where membership must be a dropdown list which allows customer to choose multiple choices (has a checkbox in front of each choice). So my questions are:

1. Is there any way to do the task with Django models built-in items?
2. If not, can I custom it and how?
   Please not that I want to the task with models only (not forms).

Model:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    MEMBERSHIP_BRONZE = 'B'
    MEMBERSHIP_SILVER = 'S'
    MEMBERSHIP_GOLD = 'G'

    MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES = [
        (MEMBERSHIP_BRONZE, 'Bronze'),
        (MEMBERSHIP_SILVER, 'Silver'),
        (MEMBERSHIP_GOLD, 'Gold'),
    ]

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    membership = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES,                  default=MEMBERSHIP_BRONZE)
```

Admin:

```
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Customer
    list_display = '__all__'


admin.site.register(Customer, CustomerAdmin)
```

I tried using multiselectfield.MultiSelectField but it only can create multiple choices, not in a dropdown list.

Comment: Why a checkbox, should the Customer be in a single membership?

Comment: Hi @MohamedElKalioby,

Comment: Yes it should be. Each customer can have one membership. But I'm just thinking about the case where Customer has multiple memberships and trying to resolve it. Assuming that the customer who use my system is an organization. They purchase my service for their employees. However, each department will have different membership.

Comment: @ThienD Did you mean multiple selection for same record ??

Comment: I think this answer help you :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897731/grouped-checkboxselectmultiple-in-django-template